# Running echo command from Java

Tags: java, cmd, runtime.exec

I want to print the output of `echo %path%` from `Java` instead of `cmd`.

I have the following code:

```
private void getPath() throws IOException {
    String getPath = "cmd.exe /C echo %path%";
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(getPath);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
    String commandOutput = "";
    while (commandOutput != null) {
        commandOutput = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(commandOutput);
    }
}
```

If I run `echo %path%` from the `cmd` the output begins with:

> C:\Oracle\Ora11\bin;C:\Oracle\Ora10\bin;C:\Program Files\Common

But the output of the `Java` program begins with:

> C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386

and only after this line, the rest of the output is similar.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running your test from IDE (eg Eclipse). Try the same from command line. BTW there is another way to print environnment variables from Java

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));
```

Comment: Indeed, I'm running it from `Eclipse` but as I stated in the question, I want to run it from `Eclipse` and not from the command line.

Comment: Right, but this is Eclipse not Java who adds JRE to the PATH

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: You can try to set PATH env in your test Run Configuration

Answer (score 3):

Looks like `Java` appends to `%path%` its own paths. Nothing else.